# Feign Registration - Spring Cloud - Change Target without ribbon over-ride

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

### Introduction

I would like to be able to have two different spring profiles, and depending on the profile to change to a hardcoded address for our feign builders.

Currently was have the following:

`return builder.target(cls, "http://" + serviceName);`

But I would actually like to do the following and over-ride the address:

`return builder.target(cls, "http://our-server:8009/" + serviceName);`

### Why

Sometimes we don't want to run all the services within our development environment. Additionally, some of the services are only available through a zuul gateway sometimes.

So we run the same code in different situations and conditions.

### Technical Details

We have the following code that we use for building our Feign Clients.

We had been using the `@FeignClient` annotation in the past, but lately we decided to start building our feignClients manually.

Example below:

```
@FeignClient(name = "ab-document-store",  configuration = MultiPartSupportConfiguration.class, fallback = DocumentStoreFallback.class)
```

We call the feignRegistrar class with the following command:

```
return registerFeignClient(DocumentStoreClient.class, true);



@RequiredArgsConstructor
//@Component
@Slf4j
public class FeignRegistrar {

    @Autowired
    private Decoder decoder;

    @Autowired
    private Encoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    private Client client;

    @Autowired
    private Contract feignContract;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

    @Autowired
    private List<RequestInterceptor> interceptors;

    public <T> T register(Class<T> cls, String serviceName, boolean isDocumentStore) {

        if(isDocumentStore){
            encoder = new MultipartFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters));
        }

        //Client trustSSLSockets = new Client.Default(getSSLSocketFactory(), new NoopHostnameVerifier());

        Feign.Builder builder = Feign.builder()
            .client(client)
            .encoder(encoder)
            .decoder(decoder)
            .contract(feignContract)
            .logger(new Slf4Logger())
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.HEADERS);

        builder.requestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
                template.header("X-Service-Name", serviceName);
            }
        });

        for(RequestInterceptor interceptor : interceptors) { 

            builder.requestInterceptor(interceptor);
        }

        log.debug("Registering {} - as feign proxy ", serviceName);

        return builder.target(cls, "http://" + serviceName);
    }

    public static class Slf4Logger extends Logger {

        @Override
        protected void log(String configKey, String format, Object... args) {
            log.info("{} - {}", configKey, args);
        }
    }
}
```

### Spring Cloud Property Over-ride

We have also been using property files such as `application-ENV.property` with entries such as the following:

```
ab-document-store.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
ab-document-store.ribbon.listOfServers: localhost:8025
```

Unfortunately, `listOfServers` is not enough for us. We would like to be able to assign a directory/path as well. Something like:

ab-document-store.ribbon.listOfServers: localhost:8025/ab-document-store

### Otherworkaround

I have thought about sneaking in a header into all requests such as `X-SERVICE-NAME` using a feign interceptor. Then we could point all services to an address (e.g. localhost:9001) , and forward/proxy those requests to localhost:9001/X-SERVICE-NAME.

However, I would prefer a much easier solution such as:

```
ab-document-store.ribbon.listOfServers: localhost:8025/ab-document-store
```

**But this doesn't work :(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Introduction

I found a solution for this using a proxy that detects a header. 
So, I have a feign interceptor on the java-side that attaches a header `x-service-name` to every feign-request.

I also have a NodeJS proxy, that analyzes requests, finds `x-service-name`, and re-writes the requests to become: `x-service-name`/`originalRequestPath`.

This allows me to have all the microservices behind a zuul gateway but also access them using a eureka-over-ride.

## Java-Feign-Interceptor

```
 Feign.Builder builder = Feign.builder()
            .client(client)
            .encoder(usedEncoder)
            .decoder(decoder)
            .contract(feignContract)
            .logger(new Slf4Logger())
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.HEADERS);

        builder.requestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
                template.header("X-Service-Name", serviceName);
            }
        });
```

### NodeJS proxy

In the example, my zuul gateway ( or another proxy ) is on localhost:9001.
I'm listening on `localhost:1200` .

```
let enableProxyForJava = process.env.ENABLE_PROXY_FOR_JAVA;
if (enableProxyForJava != undefined &&  enableProxyForJava.toLowerCase() === 'true') {
    var httpProxyJava = require('http-proxy');
    var proxyJava = httpProxyJava.createProxy();

    gutil.log(  gutil.colors.green('Enabling Proxy for Java. Set your Eureka overrides to localhost:1200.') );

    require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
        console.log("req.headers['x-service-name'] = " + req.headers['x-service-name']);
        console.log("Before req.url:"+ req.url);

        if( req.headers['x-service-name'] != undefined){
            let change =  req.headers['x-service-name'] +req.url;
            console.log("After req.url:"+ change);
            req.url = change;
        }

        proxyJava.web(req, res, {
            target: 'http://localhost:9001/'
        });

    }).listen(1200);
}
```

### Property file inside Java Application that has feign clients

```
mbak-microservice1.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
mbak-microservice1.ribbon.listOfServers: localhost:1200

mbak-microservice2.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
mbak-microservice2.ribbon.listOfServers: localhost:1200

mbak-document-store.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
mbak-document-store.ribbon.listOfServers: localhost:1200
```